# changing view to a view with fragment in android

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

im trying to use setContentView to switch to a layout with a fragment inside it
but it crashes every time
what should i do?
this is my entire code:
(it must switch to fragment_layout when i click the button in the activity_main)
(fragmant_layout has a fragment and the layout for the frgment is te layout1)
(it crashs when i cick the button to switch)

main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void switchlayout(View view) {//when the button in clicked
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);
}

}
```

the fragment class:

```
public class frgment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1,container,false);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".fragmenttest.MainActivity">




<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="switchlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="alirezamellat.fragmenttest.frgment"
    ></fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"></View>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use fragment manager and inflate the parent view with your fragment. Please take a look on this resource provided by android :: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the layout of an Activity has been set it can **not** be changed at a later time.
There are a number of ways you can achieve this from which the easiest would be to have a wrapper layout and then injecting the fragment inside it using the `FragmentManager` class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragmenttest.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="switchlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then on your button click add your fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.wrapper, MyFragment.newInstance(), "FragTag").commit();
```

Remember that you have to take care of your button since it will still be visible on top of you fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider the following points::

1. On your parent layout (activity_main.xml), inside the Relative layout, add another layout called FrameLayout.
2. On your fragment layout(fragment_layout.xml), remove the fragment and add the layouts of layout1.xml to fragment_layout.xml
3. On your fragment class (MyFragment), inflate the fragment_layout.xml to the container and return the view (class name should start with uppercase letter, so name it like MyFragment)
4. On Activity class, place the following code on onclick listener.

   ```
   //onClick on OnClickListener

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
        .commit();
   ```